# Having The Source Field be the Link Provided in Another Sitecore Item

Tags: sitecore

Suppose Item A contains the link Item B would like to use as the source of its Droplist field. How can I achieve this? I have read the Sitecore Query documentation [here](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Using%20Sitecore%20Query/Sitecore%20Query%20Syntax.aspx) and [here](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/developer/using%20sitecore%20fast%20query/using%20sitecore%20fast%20query001.pdf). It appears to me that this is not achievable using Sitecore query, but I could be mistaken. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No this is not possible. To set the source of a droplist, you can either set the root path to an item which would make the droplist populate the sub-items or you can use Sitecore query to query for specific items based on your query. This is covered in the [Data Definition Cookbook (PDF link)](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/datadefinitioncookbook-a4.pdf) under 2.4.2.

Comment: Thanks. You not only answered my question, you gave a reliable source for me to verify your answer and learn even more from.